# Posting multiple documents using postman not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

I'm trying to post data using postman, but when I tried to use multiple documents, it shows blank in my mongodb. But when I try to insert a single document, it saves the data. Please correct me, I'm new to this

**server.js**

```
app.post('/bloodinventory', function(req, res) {
    var bloodinventory= new Bloodinventories(); 
    bloodinventory.blood_group = req.body.blood_group;  
    bloodinventory.blood_category = req.body.blood_category; 
    bloodinventory.num_stock = req.body.num_stock; 
    bloodinventory.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Blood Donation already exists!' }); 
        } else {
            res.json({ success: true, message: 'Blood Donation Created!' });
        }
    });
});
```

Then in my postman, I tried to insert this data:

```
{
"bloodinventories":[
        {
            "blood_group":"A_positive",
            "blood_category":"whole blood",
            "num_stock":11
        },
        {
            "blood_group":"A_negative",
            "blood_category":"platelet",
            "num_stock":9
        }
    ]
}
```

Then nothing shows in my mongodb, result:

```
_id:5c45c6a495788ec2c47f8c8b
__v:0
```

Comment: what is your post man request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provide single document in your POST request

Example:-

```
{
    "blood_group":"A_positive",
    "blood_category":"whole blood",
    "num_stock":11
 }
```

it easly get **request.body.blood_group**, **request.body.blood_category** and show on

But when you pass Mutliple document in POST request in array form

```
{
"bloodinventories":[
        {
            "blood_group":"A_positive",
            "blood_category":"whole blood",
            "num_stock":11
        },
        {
            "blood_group":"A_negative",
            "blood_category":"platelet",
            "num_stock":9
        }
    ]
}
```

Now your request is getting a array so your request body contain **bloodinventories**. And you can access it as **request.body.bloodinventories**
Take this const and apply loop on it and insert all document.

Or Simply make API like this and always send array in every request of insert.

```
Bloodinventories.insertMany(request.body.bloodinventories).then((result) => { 
  //Success Message
}).catch(err => {
 // Error Message
});
```

It May Help For You...